# PHPExcel - sending to browser issue

Tags: php, html, excel, file, save

I have a PHP script with HTML forms for user to pick several things, after that it communicates with database and prints out the result in the form of a table. Everything is formatted with CSS.

Now I would like to make those results also saved in an xls file, ideally using some sort of a "Save file" button appearing after the script finish its work. For that to work though I have to use PHPExcel write commands in several different parts of the script. But those parts are also responsible for the output on the website.

I have tried using PEAR and recently also PHPExcel and I think I can make it work with saving the file on the server, but I couldn't do it with sending to browser option (so popping up message with 'Save file as...'). When I try to do it that way, it prints out all kinds of gibberish signs on the website and doesn't pop up with save file option at all. I found out this is  because I am printing and echoing all sort of things in between the PHPExcel write commands, but I am not sure how to do it differently.

So I guess my question is: Is it possible in PHPExcel or any other library to use its write commands all over the PHP script with all sort of echos and HTML code in between while using the send to browser option?

Thanks you in advance for answers and help.

Comment: No it isn't possible: you can't send both HTML markup ___and___ a file (of any kind, not simply Excel files) in the same response; you can't even send two separate filed of the same type in a single response.... each response type must be a single response, and must be one thing or another, not both.

Comment: Send your request for an Excel file as a single request, setting the appropriate headers for your response, and sending nothing but the Excel file in that response.... if you want to update the page as well, then that must be a separate request with its own separate response

Comment: I see, thank you for clarifying. Stil I am not sure how am I suppose to do what I wanted, but maybe I will figure it out eventually.

Comment: Treat your export link as a link to the Excel export script, and use that to generate and output nothing but the Excel file, with the appropriate Excel headers.... that should then provide the file download dialogue without affecting anything on the current web page